# How to setup an ICS file with recurring events that have lapses?

Tags: icalendar

I've hit a roadblock in trying to figure out the best way to create an ICS file that will have recurring events (and single instance events). My main issue is with recurring events, because a lot of times the recurring events could have a break in between them. Given various articles I have read about ICS file size limitations, Google only accepting 1,111 events in total for a file, what are my options for formatting the event data to accurately represent the events while maximizing the events I can fit into the file?

So far I've come up with:

Option 1: A single VEVENT for each group of recurring events that have no lapse in recurrence.

Option 2: Separate VEVENTS for every single instance of recurring events.

Option 2 seems like the most accurate representation of events, however, that would use up data quickly.

Are these basically my two options?

Answer (score 1):

If your lapse only involve a small number of instances skipped, then EXDATE may work for you.  You could generate the next x years of EXDATES perhaps.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.8.5.1

Unfortunately for you EXRULE is deprecated and applications support for that may not be there.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. It looks promising. I can't say for certain what the amount of excluded dates in a series will be. That data is user generated and unknown.